# Angular JS App persist state on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have angular Js App with nested views, the issue i am facing is when i click on F5 in nested view it gets redirected to default state, i want to persist the current state.
I can understand on reload it goes to parent ui-view to load the dependencies and after that it redirects to default view i have mapped but how can i redirect it to initial view instead of default view.

routes.js

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');
 .state('dashboard', {
                url: '/dashboard',

                },
                views: {
                    // the main template will be placed here (relatively named)
                    '': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
                        controller: 'dashboardIndexController'
                    },
                    'headbar@dashboard': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/headbar.html',
                        controller: 'headbarController'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('dashboard.home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.home.html',
                controller: 'dashboardController',
            })
        .state('dashboard.campaigns', {
            url: '/campaigns',
            templateUrl: 'views/campaigns.html',
            controller: 'showCampaign',

        })
```

dashboard controller

```
$state.go('dashboard.home');
```

when i click refresh on campaigns state it redirects back to dashboard.home, which it should be as per code but how can i persist the campaigns or other nested states after reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

#### Example

On successful landing on a page, store the current page name/url in the localStorage

```
window.localStorage.setItem('currentPage', window.location.pathname):
```

And after initialization, before redirecting to the home page, redirect to the previously stored url:

```
if (window.localStorage.getItem('currentPage')
    $state.go(window.localStorage.getItem('currentPage'));
else
    // go to home page normally
```

Comment: right! thanks how can i overlook storage. Just to add instead of window.location.pathname i used $location.$$absUrl might help others.

Comment: Nice. I was about to suggest cookies - is that a good idea as well?